# What does the CMake error-message "install FILES given directory" mean?

Tags: cmake

My attempt to configure a CMake project fails due to the following:

```
 CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:42 (install):
   install FILES given directory
   "/home/steve/udunits2/build/lib/udunits2lib.html" to install.
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   lib/CMakeLists.txt:47 (texi_doc)
```

Line 42 in the top-level CMakeLists.txt file is

```
install(FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${file}.html" DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DOCDIR})
```

and is part of a function for building .info and .html files from .texi input and installing them. `${CMAKE_INSTALL_DOCDIR}` is "share/doc/udunits".

What does this error-message mean and how do I fix the problem?

Answer (score 5):

The source-code indicates that the error message means that the `FILES` argument of the `install()` command is a directory and not the expected regular file. The reason the output `.html` "file" is a directory is because I didn't initially use the `--no-split` option of `makeinfo(1)`.

My bad.

Answer (score 1):

As to me:

```
install(
        FILES
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/test_hard1.h"
        "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/config.h"
        # DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR} #  error install FILES given no DESTINATION!

        # add include after DESTINATION, then it works
        DESTINATION include ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}
)
```

Comment: But why does it "work"?   ~   Because you gave a value "include" to the destination. When CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR keeps being empty. Which is more the problem to work on...

Answer (score 0):

CMake is getting stuck on the [`TYPE parameter of install(FILES ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#installing-files). This could happen if you're running an old version of CMake, or your CMake installation has some sort of bug.

Try add `TYPE` as follows:

```
install(FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${file}.html"
        TYPE INCLUDE
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DOCDIR})
```